# why python not converts float or any other data type to string when written with string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point

Suppose

```
p1="python"
p2="script"
r=0.242424

print(p1+" "+p2+" "+r)          #wrong or error in python
print(p1+" "+p2+" "+str(r))       #correct
```

Why do I we have to convert a float to string explicitly in Python, but other languages like Java convert it implicitly?

Comment: Because different languages are different. Python is [*strongly-typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing); there is no implicit conversion.

Comment: In Python, [explicit is better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), also what you are doing is adding a string and a float, which is not allowed. You are adding first, then printing the result.

Comment: IMHO Java and other languages get it wrong in this case... in fact in Java you can do that simply because the compiler, when translating the code, hiddenly creates a `StringBuilder` and joins the various pieces of the string, so you aren't *actually* calling any `String` method. They had to allow this because, otherwise, the code would have been really too verbose.

Comment: Yeah, because the Java idiom of writing `s = "" + x;` to convert a number to a string is really clear isn't it?!

Answer (score 3):

You don't. You only need to convert it explicitly when concatenating. `print()` will use spaces to separate arguments on its own, converting each to a string:

```
print(p1, p2, r)
```

Quoting the [`print()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream, separated by *sep* and followed by *end*.

*sep* defaults to the `' '` string.

You usually use [*string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to interpolate values into a string:

```
print("Running a {} {} to show the value of r={:.6f}".format(p1, p2, r))
```

Otherwise, trying to concatenate strings with other values does *not* convert values implicitly; this goes against the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join various data types into a string, concatenation with `+` or with the `str.join` method will require them to be strings *before* you do it.

As Martijn shows, it's not needed for printing, but that can be confusing because printing by default includes newlines and a space that separates elements separated by commas that are being printed.

If you want to implicitly convert them to strings, I recomend the `string.format` method:

```
>>> '{0} {1} {2}'.format(p1, p2, r)
'python script 0.242424'
```

This is quite a useful and efficient way to format text and not have to worry about the types, so long as you don't mind getting their default string representation.